# selecting columns using a binary table in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame x in the following order

```
             date       c1   c2   c3  c4    c5    c6   c7   c8   c9
             Jan-08     12   23   12  11    10    1    49   34   23    
             Feb-08     14   33   11  11    20    11   29   44   23
```

and so on...

I have another binary matrix that has

```
                     1    3    6
              1      0    0    1
              2      0    0    0 
              3      0    1    0
              4      1    0    0
              5      0    1    0 
              6      1    0    0  
              7      0    0    0
              8      1    1    0
              9      0    1    1
```

I want to look at my binary matrix and create a new table for each column in my binary matrix such that the new table holds only the columns from data frame x which are 1 in the binary table.
So we will create 3 data frames as a result here i.e data_frame_1, data_frame_3 and data_frame_6 where data_frame_1 is of  format

```
                     date    c4    c6     c8        
                     Jan-08  11    1      34 
                     Feb-08  11    11     44
```

data_frame_3 will be

```
                     date    c3    c5     c8   c9        
                     Jan-08  12    10     34   23 
                     Feb-08  11    20     44   23
```

Comment: Is the expected output shown correct? Should it be 11 , 1 and 34. Can you show output for all 3 data frames ?

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong earlier. Have corrected it now

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, what is the relationship between these two tables(data sets?)?

Comment: There are 4 1's in second column of binary matrix but you have only 3 value in output(which again seems wrong). 2nd row should be 11, 20 and 44 ?

Comment: @NelsonGon the rows in the binary matrix correspond to the columns in the first table. so I need to select only the columns marked 1 in the binary table

Comment: @RonakShah Edited the problem again. Hope its clear now. Thanks for the help

Comment: `date`is ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to iterate over the columns of a binary matrix, `bin`, sub-settings a dataframe, `dat`:

```r
# create test data
set.seed(1)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(18), nrow=2))
colnames(dat) <- paste0('c', 1:9)

dat
#           c1         c2         c3        c4         c5        c6         c7          c8
# 1 -0.6264538 -0.8356286  0.3295078 0.4874291  0.5757814 1.5117812 -0.6212406  1.12493092
# 2  0.1836433  1.5952808 -0.8204684 0.7383247 -0.3053884 0.3898432 -2.2146999 -0.04493361
#            c9
# 1 -0.01619026
# 2  0.94383621

bin <- matrix(sample(0:1, 27, replace = TRUE), nrow = 9)

bin
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1    1    0
#  [2,]    0    0    0
#  [3,]    1    0    0
#  [4,]    0    1    1
#  [5,]    1    1    1
#  [6,]    1    0    0
#  [7,]    1    1    1
#  [8,]    1    0    0
#  [9,]    1    0    0

# subset columns of dat, using binary vector columns defined in bin;
# drop = FALSE is included to prevent any columns with only a single "1" from
# being cast to a vector
apply(bin, 2, function(x) { dat[, as.logical(x), drop = FALSE] })
# [[1]]
#           c1         c3         c5        c6         c7          c8          c9
# 1 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 1.5117812 -0.6212406  1.12493092 -0.01619026
# 2  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 0.3898432 -2.2146999 -0.04493361  0.94383621
# 
# [[2]]
#           c1        c4         c5         c7
# 1 -0.6264538 0.4874291  0.5757814 -0.6212406
# 2  0.1836433 0.7383247 -0.3053884 -2.2146999
# 
# [[3]]
#          c4         c5         c7
# 1 0.4874291  0.5757814 -0.6212406
# 2 0.7383247 -0.3053884 -2.2146999
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` we can iterate over columns of binary matrix `mat` and convert the binary matrix to logical vector which is used to subset columns from `x` dataframe.

```
lapply(1:ncol(mat), function(i) cbind(x[1], x[-1][as.logical(mat[, i])]))

#[[1]]
#    date c4 c6 c8
#1 Jan-08 11  1 34
#2 Feb-08 11 11 44

#[[2]]
#    date c3 c5 c8 c9
#1 Jan-08 12 10 34 23
#2 Feb-08 11 20 44 23

#[[3]]
#    date c1 c9
#1 Jan-08 12 23
#2 Feb-08 14 23
```